# my joomla index.php is hacked

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Unfortunately my website hacked and index.php changes regularly to the image below. I cleaned the file and changed all passwords, but it did not work. do u know the hack method? what is the solution? Because I have so much data, I can not install a fresh copy of joomla!
[image]

Comment: If you have index.php file's copy with your localhost then upload it again.

Comment: I do it regularly to undue to hack content, but after a few hours it exactly repeats to change the index.php

Comment: If it is linux, then try to revoke write permission for index.php

Comment: How are they getting in?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay:  I'll try and say if it is any better or not.tnx

Comment: @DanWhite : I don't know

Comment: They probably hacked an other file which is changing your index.php periodically

Comment: @RadekSuski : it probably is true, but I don't know which file is it, however i searched a lot

Comment: Use the service I proposed in my answer. They are very helpful in locating hacked files

Comment: See the answer at: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/2339/120

Comment: I accidentally checked my ftp passwords and found out the new passwords were not saved! after password changes it is remaining safe till now. @RadekSuski tnx for ur hints